# How to vertically and horizontally center some content the Bulma way?

Tags: css, bulma

I would like to center content both horizontally and vertically and I would like to do it the "bulma way" (without adding extra CSS). My example is working but I feel it's "hacky".

[Here is the best I have achieved](https://codepen.io/iromain/pen/OJLbmYy)

```css
html,
body,
.container,
.section {
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="section">
  <div class="container is-flex">
    <div class="column is-flex has-text-centered">
      <div class="box">
        My content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what's your question? it seems to be working

Comment: It is but I feel like it's a hacky way

Comment: @Roman Use `is-vcentered` class in html

Comment: Thanks @MehrajKhan, it definitely feels less hacky although I still think some improvements could be made.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit**: I found the solution using the hero helper in the [Bulma docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/hero/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" />

<section class="hero is-fullheight">
  <div class="hero-body has-text-centered">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        My content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```